# Get rid of Wordpress category, tag and author archives?

Tags: categories, functions, archives

I have searched the net with no success on what should be an easy thing.

I have a highly customized blog with pages, sub pages and posts. While I rely heavily on the use of categories and tags I don't want them to be viewable in a url. The same goes for authors and date categories. Basically I wan't to throw a 404 error if someone tries to access these pages. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

The following should not be accessible:

- `example.com/category/books/`
- `example.com/tag/ebooks/`
- `example.com/author/dickens/`
- `example.com/2012/10/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

building on chrisguitarguy's answer here is a quick snippet you can drop in your theme's functions.php file to do job

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse69948_archive_disabler');
function wpse69948_archive_disabler()
{
    if(is_tag() || is_category() || is_date() || is_author())
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a [plugin for this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/archive-disabler/) -- that needs some updating, but it should still work fine.

Essentially you hook in some place late after WordPress knows what page is requested (like `template_redirect`), use one of the [conditional functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and either use `$wp_query->set_404()` or just redirect the user to a page of your choice.

To disable categories, tags, author and date archives:

```
<?php
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse69948_tag_disabler');
function wpse69948_tag_disabler()
{
    if(is_tag() || is_category() || is_date() || is_author())
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the job perfectly! Thanks a lot, also for providing the useful link to the conditional functions!

Comment: Seems kinda overkill to have this as a standalone plugin. Seems like most theme authors ought to be able to do this in functions.php or a custom plugin of their own.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy, this stops the option to search by category e.g. `&category_name`. Is there a way around it?